# How to use hololens with vuforia

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, hololens

I am having problems with setting up Vuforia to work with Hololens (1st gen). Hololens doesnt seem to track imagetargets or object targets in unity and therefore wont display my AR content. I am using the newest version of MRTK and Unity 2018.4.2 LTS. I have already tried with different guides, but none of them seem to work.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is the clipping plane. Combine both cameras and set the clipping value to 0.0001 
 Look here:
[Using MRTK and Vuforia in Unity - What Camera to choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53830695/using-mrtk-and-vuforia-in-unity-what-camera-to-choose)